# How to display the value of constants in NetBeans php on mouse hover?

Tags: php, debugging, netbeans, tooltip, constants

I use Netbeans-php to debug a php project on local computer. My problem is I can not see the tool-tip displaying the value when the mouse pointer hovers on constants. For variables, a tool-tip does pop up to display their values on mouse hover. Now I must add the constants to watches to see their values, which is not convenient. What should I do to see the popping-up tool-tip for constants? Thanks!

Comment: I also have same issue with netbeans for java. Even method or variable info is not displayed when we hover mouse.